# Limit on number of Graph API calls

Tags: facebook-graph-api, limit

I am planning to get an app developed but the developer has told me that there is a limit of 600 calls per 600 seconds per IP. The app has plenty of scenarios in which this would not suffice. Is there a way to increase the limit somehow? Or does Facebook offer any premium account or something probably with a yearly fee that does not have such a limit?

Thanks.

Comment: I can't find anything about it...

Comment: It's not per IP, it's per access token, so unless you're making a lot of calls per user you'll be fine

Comment: @Igy read its per IP & per access token. But seems like they dont care much about the IP. #Ahmed- Added an answer with infos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you exceed, or plan to exceed, any of the following thresholds please contact us as you may be subject to additional terms: (>5M MAU) or (>100M API calls per day) or (>50M impressions per day).
Pulled from : https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

100M API Queries per day should be for a single app. So that should restrict you, but I dont think that matters.

Another thing, what you mentioned in your question, and I have read that elsewhere as well.

**I've found 600 calls per 600 seconds, per token & per IP to be about where they stop you.**

Pulled from : http://www.quora.com/Whats-the-Facebook-Open-Graph-API-rate-limit

Note, it is **per token**. Every other user has a different access token and IP as well. If it happens to be a cron running from the server, still I dont think they would catch you for the IP as long as you keep changing the tokens.

Another thing to implement is the Real time updates API, which will ping you when something changes so you dont have to run a 24*7 monitoring script.

P.S : Real Time Updates is Buggy! Have experienced it myself.

Comment: The 100M thing is a policy, and beyond that you're supposed to have a contract in place, there's no hard technical limit that enforces that AFAIK, the technical limits are call limits and CPU usage limits and are applied per session (i.e per access token / per user)