# Maximum rate at which fql requests can be made

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

Hi what is the maximum rate at which fql requests can be made ?
e.g. 1000 FQL requests per day ?

I'm building an app where I will be making alot of FQL requests and I need to know what the limit is.

Answer (score 0):

[Limit on number of Graph API calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553599/limit-on-number-of-graph-api-calls)

> I've found 600 calls per 600 seconds, per token & per IP to be about
>   where they stop you.

https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

> If you exceed, or plan to exceed, any of the following thresholds
>   please contact us as you may be subject to additional terms: (>5M MAU)
>   or (>100M API calls per day) or (>50M impressions per day).

Comment: 600 calls per 600 seconds is around 1 call per second. That translates to 86,400 fql queries a day. This doesn't come even close to matching up with the >100M api call per day ? Have I misunderstood something here ?

Comment: 600 calls per 600 seconds _per token & per IP_
but 100M is for the app not just a user