# Regarding Graph Api Limits

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am able to interact with Facebook through Graph Api and fetching feeds

https://graph.facebook.com/enery/posts?access_token=+fbaccToken.FbAccToken__c+&limit=100

i am able to fetch the feeds from Facebook, but i want to know about Graph API limits.

what are the Graph API limits ? how many API requests we can make per day ? is there any other limits on Facebook .

Answer (score 2):

This is already covered in other threads, like that: [Limit on number of Graph API calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553599/limit-on-number-of-graph-api-calls)

Interesting Link: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

Answer (score 0):

Each app is given an allotment of 200 API calls per user in any given 60 minute window.