# How can I retrieve mutual friends with each friend in a single query?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I'm trying to do this using the following query:

```
SELECT uid1, uid2
FROM friend
WHERE uid1 IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) AND
      uid2 IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())
```

In both [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20uid1%0AFROM%20friend) and my script, I am getting the same response:

```
{
  "error": "Request failed"
}
```

Checkin the [FQL API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/friend) I've noticed that:

> This is the only user that this table can be queried for, the friends
>   of friends cannot be retrieved.

Moreover, I have to do this in a single query because there is a [600 calls per 600 seconds, per token & per IP limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553599/limit-on-number-of-graph-api-calls).

Is there another way to achieve what I am looking for? Even using the Graph API instead of FQL.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the mutual friends of two users via the graph API call

```
https:graph.facebook.com/{User1_ID}/mutualfriends/{User2_ID}
```

Then using a [batch request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests/) you can get mutual friend information on up to 50 'relationships' in one call

Comment: what about limits?

We currently limit the number of requests which can be in a batch to 50, but each call within the batch is counted separately for the purposes of calculating API call limits and resource limits. For example, a batch of 10 API calls will count as 10 calls and each call within the batch contributes to CPU resource limits in the same manner.

Comment: Right, you need to create a new batch call every 50 queries.