# what is the rate limit of query of facebook api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook API to crawl the feeds of the group I joined. On this page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/api-rate-limiting/ , this shows how to handle different errors, but I do not find the maximum queries I can make in one second and in one day. Does anyone know the query limit of Facebook API? Thanks!

Comment: There is not a maximum number for request you can do. We measure a lot more than number of request. Like how much CPU was spent on your queries and other stuff.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553599/limit-on-number-of-graph-api-calls?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I got the result by myself. It is 600calls per 600 seconds.

```
{u'error': {u'message': u'(#613) Calls to stream have exceeded the rate of 600 calls per 600 seconds.', u'code': 613, u'type': u'OAuthException'}}
```